# Django REST Framework BasicAuthentication is not applied as default authentication class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST Framework project and I added

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

to `settings.py` and I expect `BasicAuthentication` is applied to all pages as default but still it does not require any authentication to display the content. that is weird. Do I have to do something I did not do?
**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('student/', include('blogapp.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

**setting.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'blogapp',
]
```

**blog_app/urls**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', StudentView.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
class StudentView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

## UPDATE 1:

Also per-view authentications not work!

## UPDATE 2:

[This](https://www.filemail.com/d/apguphfbipummcx) is my project source code.

Comment: It could be because all the default permission classes are removed Try to add [IsAuthenticated](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) as a default permission class and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is not the same as permission. You'll also need to add a default permission class if you require all users to be authenticated (using one of the authentication methods you wish to use):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

Also, make sure you're testing the right view (`/api/list/`). Your project (as you linked) has two `StudentView`s, one of which is a DRF view, the other (`/student/`) isn't. The latter will not be aware of DRF configuration.